# In C recursive function behaviour that cannot be justified since recursive call use different parameter than declaration

Tags: c, function, recursion, struct, linked-list

I have my link list defined in the following way:

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* link;
} Node;

typedef struct list {
    int a;
    Node* root;
} List;
```

While deleting node with value 'x' from the above list I use following recursive function:

```
void pop(List *l, int x) {
    Node* temp = l->root;
    printf("Entered\n");

    if (temp == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    else if ((l->root)->data == x) {
        pophead(l);
        pop(l, x);
    }
    else {
        Node* previous;

        while (temp->data != x) {
            if (temp->link == NULL) {
                break;
            }
                
            previous = temp;
            temp = temp->link;
        }

        if (temp->link == NULL) {    //last element has been reached
            if (temp->data == x) {
                previous->link = NULL;
                free(temp);
            }
            else {
                return;                                    }
            }
            else {
                previous->link = temp->link;
                free(temp);
                temp = previous->link;
                List* templist = create();
                templist->root = temp;
                pop(&temp, x);  //**can replace with pop(templist,x)**
            }
        }
    }
```

The last line in the pop function(in bolds) works well with 2 variations:

Variation 1.  `pop(templist,x)` : This pases `List*` pointer as arguments.

Variation 2. `pop(&temp,x)` : This passes address of node in link list.

Variation 2 **should not ideally work** for 2 reason:

1. Function argument is not List* type
2. Pointer in C are strongly typed with address for data type they are pointing to.

Here's the complete code are as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* link;
}Node;
typedef struct list{
    int a;
    Node* root;
}List;

List* create(){
    List* temp=(List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    temp->root=NULL;
    return temp;
}
void push(List* l,int x){
    Node* temp=l->root;
    Node* n=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    n->data=x;
    n->link=NULL;
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        l->root=n;
    }
    else{
        while(temp->link!=NULL){
                temp=temp->link;
        }
        temp->link=n;
    }
}
void pophead(List * l){
    Node* temp=l->root;
    if(temp==NULL){
        return;
    }
    else{
            l->root=l->root->link;
            free(temp);
    }
}
void pop(List *l,int x){
    Node* temp=l->root;
    printf("Entered\n");
    if(temp==NULL){
            return;
    }
    else if((l->root)->data==x){

                pophead(l);
                pop(l,x);


    }
    else{
                    Node* previous;

                    while(temp->data!=x){

                        if(temp->link==NULL){
                            break;
                        }
                        previous =temp;
                        temp=temp->link;

                    }
                    if(temp->link==NULL) {    //last element has been reached
                                if(temp->data==x){
                                    previous->link=NULL;
                                    free(temp);
                                }
                                else{
                                    return;
                                }
                    }
                    else{
                            previous->link=temp->link;
                            free(temp);
                            temp=previous->link;
                            List* templist=create();
                            templist->root=temp;
                            pop(templist,x);
                    }


            }
}
void display(List* l){
    Node* temp=l->root;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("%d\n",temp->data);
        temp=temp->link;
    }
}
void main(){
    List* l1=create();
    push(l1,10);
    push(l1,20);
    push(l1,30);
    push(l1,40);
    pophead(l1);
    pop(l1,30);
    display(l1);
}
```

Comment: popNode and popList seem to be what you need

Comment: In the future, instead of providing incomplete fragments of code, please provide a [mcve] so people trying to help you can compile your code with minimal fuss.  Ideally your [mcve] should be something that you successfully compiled yourself without warnings or errors, unless your question is about how to fix the warnings and errors.

Comment: I am providing you with entire code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually has a bunch of compilation errors and warnings.  Make sure that you know how to see all the errors and warnings your compiler is reporting.  Make sure you fix all of those before assuming that your code is valid C code.

The first error I see has to do with your mistaken use of `struct Node`: that struct is not defined anywhere, but `struct node` (lowercase) is.

And when I use your code on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) with GCC, I do get a warning for the line you were concerned about:

```
<source>:55:33: warning: passing argument 1 of 'pop' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   55 |                             pop(&temp,x);  //**can replace with pop(templist,x)**
      |                                 ^~~~~
      |                                 |
      |                                 Node ** {aka struct node **}        ~~~~~~^
```

Comment: Yeah I did get a warning but no errors which I mentioned in the question for Variation 2 for pop function. But my question remains how can the above code works despite pointers in C are strongly linked to the datatypes they are defined for.  The pop functions works well can there be an explaination for this??

Comment: If it's working, it's probably just working by accident.  If you really want to understand why it's working I think you need to post your *complete* code and make sure it actually compiles and prints correct output.  That way someone can run it and look at it in a debugger without having to do a bunch of busywork to guess exactly how you tested it.  You should also say exactly what compiler version and OS you are using, and compiler options.  Basically, it's hard to believe that this code is working, so if you think it is working and want an explanation, actually *show* us that it is working.

Comment: I see you added code to your question but what we need is all the code in one code block, with proper #includes at the top, so we can compile it easily without modifying it.